# Angularjs: issue with array assignment

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i m facing an odd issue, i have defined an object (globally for application) that holds array 
object looks like

```
var _global = {
        document: {}, // represent selected item
    };
```

and in my service i have something like this

```
_global.document.signers =[{name:'test',email:'test@test.com'}];
```

its working fine. now if i push element  like

```
_global.document.signers.push({name:'test',email:'test@test.com'});
```

and in controller i use

```
var signers = _global.document.signers;
```

it works fine . view gets updated with new values

but in case if i do something

```
_global.document.signers = [{name:'newTest',email:'newtest@test.com'}];
```

global object gets updated but view doesn't render new values and if i change it to push view starts rendering new values

can some one guide me wat i m doing wrong .
any help will be appreciated

**Updated**

Thanks @shani for help i have solved it using

```
var draft = globalService.getGlobal(); //global service for maintaining global objects
$scope.draft = draft;
```

and in view

```
 <ul class="list-unstyled font-11px" >
       <li ng-repeat="(signerIndex, signer) in draft.document.signers">
    </li></ul>
```

Comment: First , do not use global variables, use a service! Second it is probably a $watch issue so post your controller / view code

Comment: i have defined a global service for mainlining global variables .secondly i didnt used watch wat i have done in my controller is $scope.signers = _global.document.signers

Comment: Again show your code ( controller / view )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your global object to your controller scope, as services are singletons if there is change in service objects, your controller will automatically react to it.

Comment: can u explain bit more :) basically i didn't get wat u mean by assign your global object to ur controller

Comment: What i do in controller basically is 

var object = globalservice.globalobject();
$scope.signers = object;

Comment: thanku its working fine my mistake was, i was directly assigning to signers rather to object Thanks again